# Paginación en Laravel 5.7 con join y order by

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Quiero crear una paginación en Laravel, algo similar a este query:

```
Select * from users u
join data d on d.user_id = u.id
where u.active = 1 and u.type = 'basic' and u.banned = 0
order by d.first DESC
```

Actualmente lo hago desde el Modelo Data:

```
class Data extends Model
{
    private static $defaultPagination = 5;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function Users()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Users', 'id', 'user_id');
    }

    public static function BasicsPagination($perPage = null)
    {
        $perPage = $perPage ?: self::$defaultPagination;

        return self::with(['users' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('active', 1)
                  ->where('banned', 0)
                  ->where('type', 'basic');
        }])->orderBy('first', 'DESC')
           ->paginate($perPage);    
    }
}
```

El problema es que esto no crea un join real, sino que me genera 3 consultas:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `data`

select * from `data` order by `first` desc limit 5 offset 0

select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in ('1', '9', '14', 
'37', '49') and `active` = '1' and `banned` = '0' and `type` = 
'basic'
```

Por lo que la paginación si la requiero de 20  y las condiciones no se cumplen con los id pasados en el ultimo query (where in) me regresa 16 en lugar de 20.

¿Conocen alguna forma de hacer un join real con laravel 5.7? 
O bien ¿Cómo hacerlo correctamente?

Answer (score 1):

Haces tu consulta mediante el modelo Data, trabajando con un whereHas que puedes revisar en la documentación de Laravel, de ahí creas la relación que ya tienes, y listo

```
$resultados = Data::whereHas('Users', function($query){
        $query->where('active', 1)
              ->where('banned', 0)
              ->where('type', 'basic');
      })->orderBy('first','DESC')->get();
```

No se si se pueda hacer al revés, los where en el Modelo de "Users" y el whereHas hacia "Data", podrías intentarlo. Espero te sirva

Comment: Justamente lo estoy realizando así, la diferencia es que lo hago directamente en el Modelo Data con un método estático, por lo que es exactamente lo mismo, si lo hago desde "Users" tengo más problemas.